# Object --> Struct?

Tags: c#, class, object, struct

How do I take an Object and convert it into a struct and vice visa?

```
public void myMethod1(object myInputObject, out string myOutputString) 
{
   myInputObject = null;
   myOutputString = "";

  //Convert object into a struct, then do something
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "convert object into a struct"? What object? You can unbox something if you're actually provided a boxed value to start with, but you can't just create a struct from any old reference type. It's really unclear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Talking about boxing/unboxig? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I suppose you want something like this:  (pseudo code)

```
class myclass
{
public int a;
public float b;

}

struct somestruct
{

somestruct(int a, float b)
{
   this.a = a;
   this.b = b;
}

int a;
float b;

}


myclass mc = new myclass();

mc.a = 125;
mc.b = 12.5;

somestruct s = new somestruct(mc.a, mc.b); //all fields of mc are now in struct somestruct
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a struct and set fields values inside your method.